# flutter minimum laptop requirement

Tags: flutter

Does macbook  pro late2011(ram16GB) handle flutter without any problems?
I’m trying to buy a laptop and I would like to know whether this mac is ok for flutter, Xcode and android studio. I’m not familiar with mac. So can someone tell me whether good to go or not. Is there any minimum requirements? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The problem isn't with Flutter, more that your XCode build times will probably be excruciatingly long. I ran some iOS builds for a flutter app I was building on a 2013 macbook and the builds took ~4-6 minutes. This was a relatively complex app, so YMMV but that's my experience. But, hot reload will offset that since you won't be doing full builds much. Depends on your patience xD

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation! what is your 2013’s RAM?

Comment: It was only 4gb RAM so it was on the lower end. Yours may perform better, it's hard to say.

Comment: I use iMac 2017 (32GB RAM) along with Macbook Air 2017 (8GB RAM). The only difference I notice is of build time. Android Studio launching time is close in both machines. But the build time takes around 25 seconds on macbook and around 15 seconds on iMac.

Comment: Thank you for help guys! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

16GB of ram is more than enough - I do builds of a pretty complicated app with many dependencies on a 2015 macbook (not pro) with 8gb of ram. As noted in the comments, the processor on the one you're looking at will be a bit slower but probably fine (I imagine a macbook pro from 2011 has a similar processor to the macbook I use).

I also generally have 20-40 tabs open in chrome, XCode open, several intelliJ projects open, + slack, spotify, finder, some extra terminals. It in't always instant but not bad either. So I'd say that a mac like this one does pretty well (although I will admit the keyboard is absolute garbage, I use an external one whenever possible).

However, what you're going to want to look out for is OS X compatibility. The 2011 model **does not support the most recent OS X**. I don't know for sure, but I'd bet that the newest XCode update isn't supported on anything but the newest OS (or at least there's no guarantee it will continue to be supported), and if you don't have the newest XCode you can't build for the newest version of iOS, and if you don't build with support for the newest version of iOS you can't deploy to the app store....

If that's not important to you, you're probably fine... but otherwise I'd worry more about getting a macbook that will be supported in the future than ram, at least past 8gb.

If you don't need a laptop, you could also consider a Mac Mini - they tend to be a bit more bang for your buck. Check out [this webpage](https://eshop.macsales.com/guides/Mac_OS_X_Compatibility) for OS X version compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for such a clear explanation. OS is the problem. That like was so helpful thanks again!

Comment: Np! It would suck to find that out once you bought it.

Comment: Hey, MacBook Air is enough for flutter or I have to get MacBook Pro. ? I'm gonna buy a new one.. so consider latest models only and let me know.

Comment: hey @akshaybhange as I said in the answer I have been using a 2015 macbook w/ 8gm ram which is similar or maybe a bit slower than the new macbook airs, and having no problem at all. So it would most likely do the trick, although will still be slower for building etc. That being said, I've also recently bought a macbook pro mostly for the extra ram - but I always have several IDE's for servers, web frontend, and the mobile app open all at the same time (plug lots of extras quite often) so I need the extra juice. If you think it'll just be a browser, IDE, and you - then the air would work fine

Comment: 2019 model of the MBA does not work... it cannot identify and connect to the ios device. Seems like USB-C is a problem but I cannot prove it.

Comment: @Richard I'd bet that's more of an issue with the particular USB-C cable or particular computer  you're using then the fact that it's an Air. Make sure you're not using a cable that came with a charger as often they don't support data transfer or at least not very high speeds. Also make sure that when you run "flutter doctor --verbose" that there are no errors.

Comment: @rmtmckenzie It's a brand new Apple cable. Also. XCode and iTunes recognizes the phone... just not flutter.

Comment: @Richard this is almost getting to the point where it'd be worth posting a new question or making a post on the forums or something. But have you checked what happens when you run ideviceinfo? If the libimobiledevice library isn't working for you, then that would explain what's going on. It might also be worth running `brew upgrade libimobiledevice`.